# Python Plotly y-axis ranges do not match for subplots and won't allow me to manually define them

Tags: python, plotly, visualization

[image: Two Plotly Scatter Plots combined in one subplot]

In my Plotly subplots, the top graph has a range of [0,10], while the bottom has a range of [0,14]. Other questions regarding this on SO ([Plotly: How to change the range of the y-axis of a subplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66842973/plotly-how-to-change-the-range-of-the-y-axis-of-a-subplot)) have suggested using the following:

```
fig.update_layout(yaxis = dict(range=[0, 14]))
fig.update_layout(yaxis2 = dict(range=[0, 14]))
```

This has not fixed the issue. It does not cause any errors, but neither does it fix my problem. I need them to have the same range in order to properly show the scale of the differences between the two.

I have tried manually adjusting the ticks but I have been unable to find a value that allows be to define the number of ticks or to manually add ticks to the y-axis.

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all your y-axes to have the same range, try this:

```py
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_yaxes='all')
```

https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.subplots.make_subplots.html